# React private route component renders twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, react-router

Im writing an React/firebase app and I'm trying to get some private routes to work.
Im using `{useAuthState}` from `react-firebase-hooks/auth` to help me authenticate.

App:

```
let App = () => {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  return (
   <Navbar
      ...
      <a href="/user" />user</a>
      ...
   />
   <Router>
       <div className='main-content'>
       <Route path='/auth/signin' component={Login} />
       <ProtectedRoute path='/user' component={UserHome} 
        isAuth={user} />
   ..
  };
```

Protected route:

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, isAuth, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        isAuth ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{ pathname: "/user/signin", state: { from: props.location } }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

But react keeps rendering the components twice, and at the first render the props are null which triggers the protected route to Redirect.
But on second render the props are all there but then it's to late and the redirect has occurred.

Is it possible to wait for all the props to load before render or redirect?
Or is there any other way to solve this?

Best regards

Comment: as far as i can tell is that the component renders without props because of the asynchronous behavior of js, so until firebase returns something the objects initialised with null values and once the firebase retrieves info it passes on to the component.  try to handle this situation with a default value of other than null, maybe false as initial value and add condition isAuth!=null && isAuth ... or maybe try to use async await in the function that sets isAuth

Answer (score 3):

Since `useAuthState` may take a while to fetch the information of the user, you should use the `loading` prop that it provides to wait for it to finish:

```
let App = () => {
  const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);
  if (loading) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Initialising User...</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
  if (error) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Error: {error}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <Navbar
      ...
      <a href="/user" />user</a>
      ...
    />
    <Router>
       <div className='main-content'>
       <Route path='/auth/signin' component={Login} />
       <ProtectedRoute path='/user' component={UserHome} 
        isAuth={user} />
    ..
  };
```

You can [read more here](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/tree/master/auth)